# JQuery center plug-in which extend the functionality

Tags: jquery

i got a piece of code for centering any element by jquery.

```
(function($){
$.fn.centerIt = function(settings){

    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.centerIt.defaults, settings);

    return this.each(function(settings){
      var options = $.extend({}, opts, $(this).data());
      var $this = $(this);

      $this.css({
        position:options.position,
        top:'50%',
        left:'50%',
        width:options.width,                 // adjust width
        height:options.height,               // adjust height
        zIndex:1000,
        marginTop:parseInt((options.height / 2), 10) + 'px'  // half of height
        marginLeft:parseInt((options.width / 2), 10) + 'px'  // half of height
      });

    });
}

// plugin defaults - added as a property on our plugin function
$.fn.centerIt.defaults = {
  width: '600px',
  height: '600px',
  position:'absolute'
}

})(jQuery);

$('#elementId').centerIt({width:'400px', height:'200px'});
```

this code is not working properly. just tell me what is wrong and what to rectify as a result it will work fine....thanks.

Comment: be more specific about what the problem is - "not working properly" does not give enough of an idea

Answer (score 2):

this line `marginTop:parseInt((options.height / 2), 10) + 'px'` is missing `,` at the end

Comment: no that line is there. plzz see my code.         marginTop:parseInt((options.height / 2), 10) + 'px'  // half of height
marginLeft:parseInt((options.width / 2), 10) + 'px'  // half of height

Comment: probably comma "," is missing.